# strange behaviour of header("Location: ...")

Tags: php

I'm calling a script with an URL like `http://appname.ls.domain.com/subfolder/script.php` that script contains a redirect `header("Location: $url");` where `$url` is like `https://app2.domain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/script.php?param1=va1&param2=val2`.

But somewhy I'm redirected to `http://appname.ls.domain.com//subfolder1/subfolder2/script.php?param1=va1&param2=val2`.

Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Post your code containing that `header` statement.

Comment: when you call `https://app2.domain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/script.php?param1=va1&param2=val2` directly, what final url do you see?

Comment: For this case, your server config files may also interfere. What is the server, and what are the cross site related rules?

Comment: Did you checked your nginx/apache etc. server config ? or haproxy things ? there may be a direction.

Comment: @SergiiP, when I paste `https://app2.domain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/script.php?param1=va1&param2=val2‌​` to adress bar of browser it works as it should, and I see this email in adress bar

Comment: and if you use curl to print out the response http headers, what is in the Location: line?

Comment: `$url` is not, by any chance, something like `ROOT_URL . '/subfolder1/ ... ` ? Where the `ROOT_URL` constant is defined as `http://appname.ls.domain.com/` ..?

Comment: @Eugeny89 so when you call `http://appname.ls.domain.com/subfolder/script.php` directly - it redirects you to wrong place, but when you call `https://app2.domain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/script.php?param1=va1&param2=val2` all fine. Add to your code, before header line something like `die($url);` is it match with destination url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to configure your virtual hosts to configure app2.ls.domain.com to work with ssl/https.

Please read more on how to do that here https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts.